# How do I distinguish a file from a directory in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, directory

I'm trying to traverse through all the subdirectories of the current directory in Perl, and get data from those files. I'm using grep to get a list of all files and folders in the given directory, but I don't know which of the values returned is a folder name and which is a file with no file extention.

How can I tell the difference?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a `-d` file test operator to check if something is a directory. Here's some of the commonly useful file test operators

```
    -e  File exists.
    -z  File has zero size (is empty).
    -s  File has nonzero size (returns size in bytes).
    -f  File is a plain file.
    -d  File is a directory.
    -l  File is a symbolic link.
```

See [perlfunc manual page for more](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#-X-FILEHANDLE)

Also, try using [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) which can recurse directories for you. Here's a sample which looks for directories....

```
sub wanted {
     if (-d) { 
         print $File::Find::name." is a directory\n";
     }
}

find(\&wanted, $mydir);
```

Answer (score 21):

```
print "$file is a directory\n" if ( -d $file );
```

Comment: The documentation for all of the file test functions can be found with "perldoc -f -X" (which is pretty unintuitive, I'll admit).

Answer (score 10):

Look at the -X operators:

```
perldoc -f -X
```

For directory traversal, use File::Find, or, if you're not a masochist, use my File::Next module which makes an iterator for you and doesn't require crazy callbacks.  In fact, you can have File::Next ONLY return files, and ignore directories.

```
use File::Next;

my $iterator = File::Next::files( '/tmp' );

while ( defined ( my $file = $iterator->() ) ) {
    print $file, "\n";
}

# Prints...
/tmp/foo.txt
/tmp/bar.pl
/tmp/baz/1
/tmp/baz/2.txt
/tmp/baz/wango/tango/purple.txt
```

It's at http://metacpan.org/pod/File::Next

Answer (score 5):

```
my $dh = opendir(".");
my @entries = grep !/^\.\.?$/, readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;

foreach my $entry (@entries) {
    if(-f $entry) {
        # $entry is a file
    } elsif (-d $entry) {
        # $entry is a directory
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
my @files = grep { -f } @all;
my @dirs = grep { -d } @all;
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to use `File::Find`.