# Test if file is NOT a directory in Perl

Tags: perl, file, operators, conditional-statements

I'm aware you can test if a file is a directory using:

```
if(-d $filename)
```

but how can you test if it's not a directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I distinguish a file from a directory in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206320/how-do-i-distinguish-a-file-from-a-directory-in-perl)

Comment: The canonical Stack Overflow question is *[How do I distinguish a file from a directory in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206320)*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you thought of trying the following?

```
if (! -d $filename) ...
```

The result of `-d` is, after all, something that can be treated as a boolean value, hence the logical not operator `!` will work fine.

And, if you're after something *more specific* than "not a directory", see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html). There are quite a few things that aren't directories that it sometimes doesn't make sense to treat as regular files.

Keep in mind that's assuming you've already validated that the filename *exists.* If you do a `! -d` on a non-existent filename, it will return true.

It's a philosophical matter as to whether you consider a non-existent thing to be "not a directory" but, if you want to ensure it exists as well, you can use `! -d` in conjunction with `-e`, something like:

```
if ((-e $filename) && (! -d $filename)) ...
```

Comment: I just couldn't get to 30 characters fast enough ... I think the question actually stunned me.

Comment: Please note: depending on how you parse OP's need, this answer may be wrong. The way I parsed it, he wants to know whether something is a file BUT not a directory - this answer would return true even for something that's NOT a file in the first place (e.g. `!-d NO_SUCH_FILE` returns true).

Answer (score 5):

To test if something is a file, BUT not a directory, you need to simply combine the 2 tests (there's no single test):

```
if (-e $file && !-d $file) { # a file but not a directory }
```

Please note that:

- With all due respect, paxdiablo's answer is wrong for the way the question is worded ( pure `!-d` does not work for what the user asked as it checks if a random thing/string is not a directory, NOT whether something is a file which is not a directory). E.g. `!-d NO_SUCH_FILE` returns true.
- Greg's answer may be correct depending entirely on whether the original user meant to include non-plain files (e.g. symbolic links, named pipes, etc..) in their definition of "file which is not a directory". If they meant to include all those special "files", Greg's answer is also wrong as "-f" excludes them (as Greg wisely noted in his answer in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it):

```
unless (-d $filename)
```

Comment: Very elegant though

Answer (score 2):

The `-f` operator tests to see whether something is a "regular file". This excludes directories, but also excludes such things as pipes and device nodes.

```
if (-f $filename) { ...
```