# excluding directories in file tests for perl

Tags: perl

I am taking arguments from the command line to test if they exist print out their names if they do. In this code directories are printed out if they exist. How do I exclude directories?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


foreach my $x (@ARGV) {
  if (-e $x){
    print "$x ";
  else {
    print "'$x' does not exist"
  }
}
exit;
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I distinguish a file from a directory in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206320/how-do-i-distinguish-a-file-from-a-directory-in-perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the file test operator `-d` to test if you have a directory.

In your code, you can skip directories by adding:

```
next if -d $x;
```

See [perldoc -f -X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) for details on this and all other file test functions.